# Can one win points for acting both for and against belief in a session?

Tags: mouse-guard

Page 52 of the Mouse Guard manual states "if your character's actions in the game reflect his Belief, you earn one fate point. You may get this award once per session." [Example follows]

Page 53 states "It's hard to quantify, but if you play against your Belief in a cool and dramatic fashion... you earn a persona point."

I interpret this as meaning you can earn both the Fate point and the Persona point, acting for and against your Belief in the same session. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because I don't know the system - is there any rule that would prevent it? Because during one session you can perform a lot of actions, and doing something your character considers really bad, due to dire need and desperation, does not mean he does not follow his beliefs overall.

Comment: @Mołot knowing if there's some rule preventing it is, I think, the core of the question.

Comment: @Mołot FYI, it's not about doing something you think is bad, it's about dramatically struggling with, and overcoming, your preconceptions and beliefs. Character-growth stuff. (So yeah, as okeefe says below, you can act to pursue a belief, and later reverse that dramatically, all in one session.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can act both for and against your belief (as part of different actions, of course) to earn both rewards.

Comment: Exactly; This is not contradictory at all - in one situation, you may follow your belief, and in another, you may decide that other things are more important.